# Why is Incremental Search Agonizingly Slow in Visual Studio 2012/2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm running visual studio 2012 and I've noticed lately that incremental search is absurdly, painfully, blood-pressure-risingly slow. Here are the major extensions I have as well:

- Resharper 8.1
- Emacs Emulation extension (modified slightly to get it to work with VS 2012 [all you do is change the version attribute in the XML])

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some experimentation turning extensions on and off, it turns out that this was because **the instance of Visual Studio was running for an exceptionally long time. (on the order of days)**

**Closing and restarting Visual Studio** made incremental search go back to its normal speed.

Comment: Excellent! My exact problem in VS 2013. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exceptionally" here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - a few days, IIRC.

Comment: OK, I don't think I ever have VS2013 running more than a few hours at a time before exiting out and doing other stuff, yet incremental search is super-slow for me, even for relatively small (<100 lines of code) files. I will try to restart it when I notice it and report back what my experience was.

Comment: Interesting, I've had VS2012 running for weeks (with the same large solution open all the time), and never hit this problem. Btw, don't forget to accept your own answer.

Comment: Still repros on VS2015.